# custom validation issue in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i am trying to add custom validation in rails association.

`financial` has_many association with `payment_milestone`

`financial`has attributes `year1` and `year2` and 
`payment_milestone`has attribute `amount`.

now i want when ever i create multiple `payment_milestone` of `financial`,  `amount` of total and newly creating `payment_milestone` should not exceed total of `year1+year2` of parent`financial`

current code only check each `payment_milestone` `amount`is either equal or less than parent `financial` `year1+year2`, while creating new`payment_milestones`.

payment_milestone.rb

```
  belongs_to :financial
  validate :cost_head_validation


  def cost_head_validation
    if financial.year1+financial.year2 <=  amount
      errors.add(:amount, "you are exceeding financial cost head")
    end
  end
```

Comment: If it _"should not exceed year1 and year2 combined value of parent financial"_, shouldn't it be `>=` (greater or equal than)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma, i think you understood wrong, just modified question to make it more simple. actually ```year1``` and ```year2``` are attributes of ```financial``` in ```payment_milestones``` all combined, it should be less than of parent ```financial```

Comment: What version of `rails` are you using?

Comment: I think @SebastianPalma is correct. But let me suggest a better development approach. Show us your test script. Don't have any? Well then, write a test script for the valid and invalid cases, and I think your problem will be solved as you get the scripts to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have has_many relation between `financial` and `payment_milestone`

payment_milestone.rb

```
def PaymentMilestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :financial
  validate :cost_head_validation


  def cost_head_validation
    if financial.year1+financial.year2 <=  financial.payment_milestones.sum(:amount) + amount
      errors.add(:amount, "you are exceeding financial cost head")
    end
  end
end
```

Here I'm adding all the payment milestone amounts related to financial to validate. Hope, it works.

Comment: @thanks this worked but one problem is it act like only less than operator not less than equal to . i checked data type and converted both to float but still operator act like less than.

Comment: R u sure u typecasted like this (financial.year1+financial.year2).to_f <= (financial.payment_milestones.sum(:amount) + amount).to_f . If so, then what are the values of lhs and rhs. Please paste the values here.

Comment: even i try to create only only ```payment_milestone``` of financial it accepts 0.01 less in rhs w.r.t to lhs. if lhs is 10 rhs is only accepts till 9.99